# Can't get function .on("click")

Tags: jquery

I can't get the "createMyEvent" function with "span id="detailKalender".
Every time i load the "detailPage", the createMyEvent function fires. It should fire only on click by the span "#detailKalender". Any suggestions?

I'm using: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/pre-3.0, jquery-1.11.0, jquery.mobile-1.3.2 and phonegap 2.9.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  // JavaScript
  $('#detailPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
      var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
      $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getDetail.php?id='+id, displayDetail);
   });

  function displayDetail(data) {
      var detailVar = data.item;
      console.log(detailVar);

  // title            
      $('#detailTitel').text(detailVar.titel);
  //location      
      $('#detailLocation').text(detailVar.location);
  // date     
      $('#detailDatum').text(detailVar.datum);    
  // end date     
      $('#detailDatumEnde').text(detailVar.datumEnde); 

  createMyEvent(detailVar);   
  }
  //  Calendar
   // prep some variables
   function createMyEvent(detailVar){

        var startDate = new Date(detailVar.datumStart);    
        var endDate = new Date(detailVar.datumEnde);   
        var title = detailVar.titel;                                                   
        var location = detailVar.location;                                          
        var notes = "myNotes";
        var success = function(message) { alert("my alert"); };
        var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };

        // create
        window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);    
  }           

  function getUrlVars() {
      var vars = [], hash;
      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
      for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
      {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
      return vars;
  }
```

html:

```
    <div id="detailPage" data-role="page">
    <span id="detailKalender">kalender</span>
    <script>          
        $( "#detailKalender" ).on("click", createMyEvent);
    </script>   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a page loads, the following function is called

```
$('#detailPage').live('pageshow', function(event) { // live() is deprecated
  var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
  $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getDetail.php?id='+id, displayDetail);
});
```

So when the JSON is loaded, it calls the callback function, in this case `displayDetail()`.
That function looks like

```
function displayDetail(data) {

    ... code

    createMyEvent(detailVar);   
}
```

and there you have it, you're calling the `createMyEvent()` function on every pageload

Comment: how can I do it right? I need it there to get the variables.

Comment: Well, either you want to call that function on pageload, or you don't? If you need to call the function on pageload, then you can't expect it to be called on click only ?

Comment: can't do that with something like return false?

Comment: Should I load two different scripts, one on pageload and another for the createMyEvent() function? Do you know why the #detailKalender is not getting the function. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really don't know how this works, there are too many custom functions and things, so I can't test it or see what you see, I can only tell you why the function is called on every pageload, and not just on click, and you have to decide, either you call it on every pageload, or you don't, there's not much else I can tell you ?

Comment: adeneo, thank you for your help! I try to separate them in two javascript files, to make two different calls. Greetings to Norway from Switzerland!